# laravel dynamic tab with title and content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

currently i am working on product showcase website. in this website i have to show tab with dynamic nav and content. if any one can help me than please share your idea.. thanks in advance.

  -

### Nav-tabs Dropdown Vertical

Dropdown appears at width less than or equal to 768px   Tabs  Tab 1

Tab 2

Tab 3

#### Tab 1

Place a link with the class `.nav-tabs-dropdown.btn.btn-block.btn-primary` above the tabs list and add an id of `#nav-tabs-wrapper` to the tabs list for the dropdown to work.

```
  a href="#" class="nav-tabs-dropdown btn btn-block btn-primary">Tabs/a>
ul id="nav-tabs-wrapper" class="nav nav-tabs nav-pills nav-stacked wells">...
```

#### Tab 2

Mauris imperdiet dignissim ante, in efficitur mauris elementum sed. Cras vulputate malesuada magna. Morbi tincidunt eros a dui cursus, vitae dignissim nulla scelerisque. Duis pharetra scelerisque mi vel luctus. Cras eu purus efficitur, blandit nisi id, fringilla nulla.

#### Tab 3

Etiam id pharetra quam. Morbi tristique nunc vel sapien dapibus, sit amet imperdiet quam venenatis. Vestibulum et suscipit urna. Suspendisse volutpat quis est eu volutpat. Nulla non tortor venenatis turpis congue aliquet. Vivamus at elit vel massa elementum tempor sit amet sed odio. Nullam placerat, arcu sed ullamcorper ornare, erat erat placerat quam, in feugiat nulla purus in nunc. Maecenas vitae erat auctor, aliquam tellus et, vulputate eros.

### Nav-tabs Dropdown Horizontal

Dropdown appears at width less than or equal to 768px

Tabs  Tab 1

Tab 2

Tab 3

#### Tab 1

Add the class `.nav-tabs-horizontal` to the tabs list for the dropdown to work with horizontal tabs.

a href="#" class="nav-tabs-dropdown btn btn-block btn-primary">Tabs/a>
ul id="nav-tabs-wrapper" class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-horizontal">

#### Tab 2

Mauris imperdiet dignissim ante, in efficitur mauris elementum sed. Cras vulputate malesuada magna. Morbi tincidunt eros a dui cursus, vitae dignissim nulla scelerisque. Duis pharetra scelerisque mi vel luctus. Cras eu purus efficitur, blandit nisi id, fringilla nulla.

#### Tab 3

Etiam id pharetra quam. Morbi tristique nunc vel sapien dapibus, sit amet imperdiet quam venenatis. Vestibulum et suscipit urna. Suspendisse volutpat quis est eu volutpat. Nulla non tortor venenatis turpis congue aliquet. Vivamus at elit vel massa elementum tempor sit amet sed odio. Nullam placerat, arcu sed ullamcorper ornare, erat erat placerat quam, in feugiat nulla purus in nunc. Maecenas vitae erat auctor, aliquam tellus et, vulputate eros.

---

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is unclear and not well formatted....Please elaborate more, on where, what and using what code, produces your error. And finally what your desired result will be...